# Limit of matrix raised to the power of $n$ when sum of absolute values of row is < 1

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, limits

I am trying to prove that the following statement is true (it may be wrong):

If $\sum_{j=1}^n|a_{ij}|<1$ then $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} A^{n+1}x = 0$.

The following is what I started to do, but I still end up stuck with a term that's not very helpful and I'm not even sure if this is the right approach:

$A^{n+1}x = A^{n}Ax = A^n\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}x_j \leq A^n\sum_{j=1}^n |a_{ij}| |\max_j\{x_j\}| < A^n |\max_j\{x_j\}|$

As you can see, I still have a power and cannot yet take a limit here to obtain 0.

Any advice would much appreciated :)

Comment: Is the absolute-sum less than unity along each row or column? In the question is along each column but in your method you have assumed it is along each row.

Comment: Typo in condition - just fixed :)

Comment: Perhaps you can consider the spectral radius.

Comment: Just a general suggestion: Do not use $n$ both as the size of the matrix and as a dummy variable for the power of the matrix. And don't write inequalities with matrices unless you're very specific about what that means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A=Q\Lambda Q^{-1}$ denotes the eigen-decomposition of $A$ and $\lambda_k$'s are its eigenvalues. Note that
$$\max_k|\lambda_k|\leq\max_i\sum_{j}|a_{ij}|\leq 1$$
and $A^n=Q\Lambda^nQ^{-1}$. Then, one may see that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\Lambda^n=0$.

Comment: How can we be sure that the eigen-decomposition exists? Also - where does the first inequality derive from?